# Can't use a method in another class to print out array list results

Tags: java, list, class, methods

I'm trying to use a method in another class to print out result stored in a list, in that class, but i'm having trouble using a method from another class.
Here is the method i'm using in the class event, where the list is stored:

```
public void listParticipantResult(Participant participant) {
    ArrayList<Result> results = sortResults();

    for (Result result : results) {

        if (result.getParticipant().getId() == participant.getId()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where i'm trying to call the method in my main program, 
but the method in the class Event cannot be resolved. I'm not sure how to declare it as an object so i can use the method.

```
    private void participantResult() {
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    int participantNumber = readInt();

    Team team = null;
    Participant participant = null;

    for (Team teamFromList : teamList){
        if (teamFromList.hasParticipantWithId(participantNumber)) {
            participant = teamFromList.getParticipantById(participantNumber);
            team = teamFromList;    
        }   
    }
    if (participant == null) {
        System.out.println("Participant with number " + participantNumber + " does not exist.");
        return;
    }
    else {
            event.listParticipantResult(); <- right here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: isn't it just that you do not pass the participant as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Event object

```
Event event = new Event(); //Or something similar based on constructor
```

You need to then make sure you are passing in a Participant as your Event.listParticipantResult() requires.

Comment: When i tried this, using my constructor, like this;
 else {
   Event event = new Event(null, participantNumber);
   Event.listParticipantResult(participant);
   }
  }
it says "can't make static reference to non static method" :/

Comment: It needs to be event.listParticipantResult(participant);

Answer (score 1):

`listParticipantResult(Participant participant)` takes one argument of type `Participant`. On the 3rd line from the bottom, you are not passing any arguments:

```
...
event.listParticipantResult();
...
```

Change it to:

```
...
event.listParticipantResult(participant);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare `event`? You also don't pass in any argument to the `listParticipantResult()` call, shouldn't you be passing in a `Participant` object?